# Question regarding with complex charts in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, charts

I need to build complex charts in two content pages inside my xamarin forms app. My application must be able to work offline, so using something from the internet is not allowed in this case

This library should be able to mix in the same graphic:

-Line Series
-Error Bar series (horizontal and vertical)
-Bar series with custom x axis labels
-Scatter series

please tell me any library that you know and that has such characteristics

Comment: You need to read the help before asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, you will notice this is too-broad and we dont answer "what library" questions

Comment: Having a look at [SfSchedule](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfschedule/getting-started).Maybe helpful for you, and you can detail describe wants with some image .

Comment: Maybe [Microcharts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/) might be helpful.